# Provided id of the wrong type for class com.demo.model.Condidat. Expected: class com.demo.model.CondidatKey, got class java.lang.Long

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

---

### Composite class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CandidatKey implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Setter
@Getter
private long id;
@Setter
@Getter
private String cin;
}
```

---

Candidat

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "candidat")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(CandidatKey.class)
public class Candidat {
@Getter
@Setter
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private long id;
@Getter
@Setter
@Column(name="cin")
@Id private String cin;
}
```

---

### Controller:

```
 @CrossOrigin
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
 public class CandidatController {
 @Autowired
private CandidatRepository candidatRepository;

@GetMapping("/candidats")
public List<Candidat> getAllCandidats(){
    return candidatRepository.findAll();
}
@GetMapping("/candidat/{id}")
public Optional<Candidat> getCandidat(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return candidatRepository.findById(id);
}
```

im getting this error in http://localhost:8080/api/v1/candidat/1 :

ERROR 11716 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: **Provided id of the wrong type for class com.example.demo.model.Condidat. Expected: class com.example.demo.model.CondidatKey, got class java.lang.Long;** nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.example.demo.model.Condidat. Expected: class com.example.demo.model.CondidatKey, got class java.lang.Long] with root cause

Answer (score 1):

Id of your Candidat entity is defined as a composite key of CandidateKey class. So findById method expects object of this type as a parameter, while the controller provides Long value passed as url variable.

Comment: So what should i do ? i want to find the candidat with only one attribute from the composite class (cin or id)

Comment: It depends what your api is supposed to do at the end. For example If both attributes (id and cin) are uniqe in the database, you can use only one of them as id. Then set id as @Id in the repository, remove CandidatKey class, prepare additional method findByCin and update your controller. In the controller you can have separate mapping for id and cin input or you can have one mapping and then a method which will recognize whether id or cin was input and then call correct find method.

Answer (score 1):

```
     public interface CondidatRepository extends 
     JpaRepository<Condidat, CondidatKey>{    {
     @Query(value = "select * from candidat c where c.cin 
     =? 
     1", nativeQuery = true)
     Optional<Condidat> findCondidat(@Param("cin") 
     String cin);  
}
```